# How to convert rows into columns with codeigniter active record pattern?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

Here is my table

```
+------+------+-------------+
| sid  | cid  | amount      |
+------+------+-------------+
| 32   | 1    | 500         |
+------+------+-------------+
| 33   | 1    | 300         |
+------+------+-------------+
| 32   | 2    | 500         |
+------+------+-------------+
| 33   | 2    | 400         |
+------+------+-------------+
| ..   | .    | ...         |
+------+------+-------------+
| ..   | .    | ...         |
+------+------+-------------+
| 32   | n    | 100         |
+------+------+-------------+
| 33   | n    | 100         |
+------+------+-------------+
```

In my view I want to show it in my view like

```
+------+----------+-----------+------+------------+------------+
| sid  | amount(1)| amount(2) |  ... | amount(n)  |Total amount|
+------+----------+-----------+------+------------+------------+
| 32   | 500      | 500       |  ... | 100        |1100        |
+------+----------+-----------+------+------------+------------+
| 33   | 300      | 400       |  ... | 100        |800         |
+------+----------+-----------+------+------------+------------+
```

How should I do it?

Comment: This can be done via dynamic pivot query

Comment: This is _not_ a merge; it's a _pivot_.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Comment: @RayToal what should I write in the title?

Comment: @Alvi_1987 php/mysql how to convert rows into columns

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT`, `SUM` and `GROUP` clause of SQL. However, there won't be multiple columns for amount. The list of amount for a sid will all be in one single column with values separated by comma.

```
SELECT sid,
       GROUP_CONCAT(amount) AS amount,
       SUM(amount) AS total
FROM mytbl
GROUP BY sid;
```

Comment: Since you are going to use PHP, you can get the individual amounts from the amount column using something like:<?PHP
$amount_set = "500,500,100";
$amount = explode(",", $amount_set);
echo $amount[0];
?>

Comment: I second this answer for simplicities sake; unless you are using a database that supports pivots out of the box.